# What happens when you pull too much power from the DC-DC converter of an electric car?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, automotive

Electric cars use a DC-DC converter to charge the 12 V service battery and power the various 12 V devices from the ~400 V traction battery.

What happen if you pull too much amps from it? Does it break somehow or does it just provide the maximum power it can?

I can't find any spec about the converter itself. How could I determine the maximum amps it can provide?

Comment: The excess current is supplied by the service battery -- that's why it's there!

Answer (score 3):

They have built-in protection, there's no danger of damage.  Usually, overcurrent protection and overtemperature protection.  How the supply handles an overcurrent condition is a system design choice.  It could just supply the maximum safe current, or it could shut down for some period of time and re-try (hiccup) or it could shut down and alert the user via a DTC or dash light and maybe require a re-start to try again

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's perfectly common in a fuel automobile for transient loads to exceed the output of the alternator. It's rainy so you have wipers, A/C and blower maxed out for defogging, rear defogger turned on, and you're also parallel parking, which is a worst-case load for electric power steering.  With the engine at idle, the alternator *is not* keeping up.

That's what the 12V battery is for... the battery is like a UPS or voltage stabilizer, but for DC. The transient high load simply borrows from the battery.  The battery is still there in an electric car, in fact it's needed since *more stuff* is 12V electric - no vacuum to run the brake assist.  They're not going to use a 400V power steering unit when 12V units have existed for 20 years and work fine.

This is "normal operation" **and the DC/DC converter is sized for this** (i.e. to cover average loads not peak ones). The DC/DC is designed to "cope" with this normal scenario of DC loads temporarily overdrawing the output of the DC/DC.  So it will self-limit or otherwise thermally limit.